# Adding a button in a block that links to a page of another plugin

Tags: php, html, moodle

I'm fairly new to moodle and php in general.
I created a new block which acts like a display for custom events and reminder.
Inside that block is a button that should open the page of another plugin I created when clicked.
But I can't manage to set the button with a link that opens the new page.
When I press the button, nothing happens.
If I enter the address of the page of the other plugin in the address bar, it opens as expected.

```
    global $CFG;
    global $DB;
    $mform = $this->_form;

    $reminderinfo='';
    $reminder = $DB->get_records('reminder_events');
    foreach ($reminder as $remind){
        $reminderinfo .= $remind->eventname . '  ' . $remind->time . '<br>';
    }

    $manageurl = $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/reminder/manage.php';
    // Add reminderinfo to mform
    $mform->addElement('html', '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Reminder" onclick=\"location.href="'.$manageurl.'"\">');
```

Image of Inspector mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---update---

```
'<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Reminder" onclick=\"location.href="'.$manageurl.'"\">'
```

Because you are using single quotes at the beginning of the string, there is no need to add a backslash before the double quotes.

You can fix it like the example:

```
'<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Reminder" onclick="location.href=\''.$manageurl.'\'">'
```

Comment: I added the image you asked for in my initial question.

Comment: ```onclick = "\"location....\""```

remove the \" then try it again.

Comment: You would rather comment the user's question as you don't give any solution for the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

here's some tips

Never use literal language strings, always store the string so it can be translated. Not just for different languages but also different versions of a language, eg US English and British English.

In `/local/reminder/lang/en/local_reminder.php` add this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$string['addreminder'] = 'Add Reminder';
```

Then use the language string with

```
get_string('addreminder', 'local_reminder');
```

Don't use `$CFG->wwwroot` directly for creating urls.

```
$manageurl = $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/reminder/manage.php';
```

Use this instead

```
$manageurl = new \moodle_url('/local/reminder/manage.php');
```

Then you have 2 options.

Either create a link that is styled to look like a button and use the `target` attribute to open in a new window

```
$managelink = \html_writer::link($manageurl, get_string('addreminder', 'local_reminder'),
    ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'target' => '_blank']);
```

Or use the button renderer with the `target` attribute

```
$button = $OUTPUT->single_button($manageurl, get_string('addreminder', 'local_reminder'),
    'get', false, ['target' => '_blank']);
```

And a final tip

It's unusual to open a link in a new window in Moodle. This is because of accessibility. So I wouldn't recommend it.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G200.html

> In general, it is better not to open new windows and tabs since they can be disorienting for people, especially people who have difficulty perceiving visual content.